# Sharepoint 2010 Projects not showing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have installed sharepoint 2010 and the sdk, yet I cannot see / open sharepoint projects in Visual Studio. When I go to new >> Project, sharepoint is not anywhere in the options.

If I try and open an event receiver project, I get this project type is not supported in this installation.

I have tried reinstalling the Sharepoint 2010 SDK, and repairing VS 2010 Premium.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2010 premium.  Go Figure!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running VS 2010 Professional and when I ran VS 2010 SP1 it crashed during installation. After that I got the same error message when I opened a solution containing Sharepoint 2010 projects. I tried the following but it didn't solve it:
 - Running VS 2010 repair
 - Reinstalling VS2010 SP1
 - Reinstalling .Net framework 4.0
Same error...
Finally I ran VS2010 setup, 'add remove features', and noticed that the 'Sharepoint Developer Tools' was not included anymore. I added it and now it works!